# How to limit an app to one type of layer in AWS Opsworks?

Tags: github, amazon-web-services, continuous-integration, aws-opsworks

How do I limit an app to just be deployed to one layer per default in AWS Opsworks?

I have set up a webhook from Github to automatically deploy my app to Opsworks but the app is deployed to all my layers when it should only be deployed to one layer.

Comment: I think I'm facing the same issue: when I push code to one Github repo, all my layers are redeployed. Is it the expected behaviour? Did you find a fix?

Comment: No - sorry - no fix was available. I'm switching to CoreOs and Docker for all deployments now instead of Opsworks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I struggled for a bit with the same question and I think I finally got an answer:

1. Create a new SNS topic.
2. Create an AWS Lambda function that launches the deploy for you on whatever you want using the JavaScript AWS-SDK. So you can get the idea:

```js
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config.region = 'us-east-1'; // Opsworks only uses this one for Stacks in any region
var opsworks = new AWS.OpsWorks();
opsworks.describeStacks({}, function(err, data) {
  console.log(data);
  context.succeed(message);
});
```

3. Assign the required policies to this lambda function to allow whatever you call from the AWS API.
4. Set Github to send the notification to the SNS topic rather than calling Opsworks directly.

Answer (score 0):

If possible, please provide the screenshot showing how your layers and instances are setup. I think it may be a misconfiguration that is causing the layers to install the application.

By default Opsworks wont install applications on all the layers unless it's specified in the set of layers to run the related recipe for that instance.

Comment: Thanks. I tried to clarify. The question is about how I can limit the app to only be deployed to one (or more) layers in Opsworks. Right now it seems to try to deploy the app to all layers in my stack.

Comment: @ChristianLandgren can you show the screenshot of how you are laying out the layer recipes ? It would make it easier to determine if this is happening because you're accidentally using deploy all type situation in your structures. If the recipes are opensource, linking them would be helpful too

Comment: I have nothing special in my recipes, however I have customized the cookbooks and they are open sourced so please look through them if you think it might be the cause of the problem. https://github.com/irony/opsworks-cookbooks. This is my layer recipe: http://cl.ly/image/2m2U0S1G3Z2x